# is stackexchange.redis a "smart client" when using Redis cluster?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

A smart client for Redis cluster will "take persistent connections to many nodes, will cache hashslot -> node info, and will update the table when they receive a -MOVED error".

I checked numerous documents but can't find a definitive answer on whether Stackexchange.Redis is a smart client. Can anyone advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Stackexchange.Redis client in my web application to connect to Redis cluster having 6 instances of Redis servers. Stackexchange.Redis client works perfectly with Redis cluster and we did not get -MOVED error.